# Run a a java program automatically when another java programs executes

Tags: java, triggers, actionlistener, invoke

I have two separate Java programs on the same machine. I want to have one java program execute automatically when the other programs starts i.e if program A runs, program B should automatically start running too.

I do not want to make program B a part of program A, then create an instance of program B in class of program A to call to make the call. Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Comment: This would be an interesting question on [su] (assuming you mean "only on my computer")

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that will start both programs.    For example, on Windows, you would create a .bat file that runs program A followed by program B.     This is not JAVA per se, it is OS dependent.

Comment: Hi Dom. I do not want this to depend on OS as i plan to configure the program making the trigger as part of flow is an ESB (Mule). So it should depend on the Mule ESB flow. Ideally, prog B should be a Java component in a Mule Flow.

Comment: May be i should point out that i am running the programs on linux if that makes the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have Program A start Program B, for example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar progB.jar");
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives me an error saying "i cannot make a static reference to a none-static method exec(String) from the type Runtime"

Comment: @TheGeorgia Did you use `Runtime.exec()` or `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`?  Confirm again that you followed the example code.

Comment: I used Runtime.exec() as suggested.

Comment: @TheGeorgia The correct usage is `Runtime.getRuntime().exec`.

Comment: May be i should point out that i am running these programs in linux if this changes anything?

Answer (score 0):

In program A add this line to the main method. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar /path/to/program.jar");`

Comment: Hi Handuel. I tried but does not do anything. Program B is simple and only prints "Hello World". But when i run program A using your suggestion, i do not get any results in the console window.

Comment: Ah, it's running through the console. The problem here is that the process for program b is getting run, but it's output isn't being sent to the console.

Comment: So how can i confirm that progB is actually being run? If this is the case, then that is exactly what i want as the console display is just a test to make sure progB runs when progA runs. So again, how do i confirm progB is running?

Comment: Can you please provide me with an example of what progB may look like to make your suggestion valid?

Comment: Add this to prog b: Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer"); If my documents opens then prog b ran.

Comment: Since i am running on Linux, this won't work. But i get the idea of what you mean. So i tried to Runtime.getRuntime().exec(java -jar /path/to/progB.jar") with progB designed to output a simple string to an output file in a local directory. However, it does not seem to work. When i run progB directly, it outputs to the file okay. But when i try to run it using the suggested command from another program, it does not output to a file.